# Line-breaking equations in a tabular environment

Tags: tables, equations, align, breqn

The following code produces error `! Missing \endgroup <inserted text>.` What is causing the error? It seems that the `breqn` is not working inside tabular environment.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{breqn}
\begin{document}
\begin{tabular}{l}
\begin{dmath*}
  f (1.02) + f (1.06) + f (1.1)  + f (1.14) + f (1.18) + f (1.22) + 
  f (1.26) + f (1.3)  + f (1.34) + f (1.38) + f (1.42) + f (1)
\end{dmath*}
\end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Just out of idle curiosity: What's your use case for embedding a `dmath*` environment inside a single-column `tabular` environment?

Comment: For referencing purpose. The output is put in a table which is referred.

Comment: @user61681 You don't need a `tabular` inside a `table` environment. You can have anything; of course you need a caption if it should be referenced.

Comment: Thank you for making it clear. I need referencing with caption.

Comment: So you need a `table` (or maybe `figure`?) environment in order for `\caption` (and `\label`) to make sense. You do *not* need to encase the `dmath*` environment in a `tabular` environment inside said `table` environment.

Comment: Yes. I got the point. Thank You. I will make it that way.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`dmath` is a vertical display construct so can not work in an `l` column which is like `\mbox`. Use a `p{...}` column so it is in vertical mode, and has a target width for line breaking.

Comment: @user61681 as egreg commented later, a one row one column tabular isn't needed at all, I assumed that was just an artifact of making a minimal example so did not comment on that here.

Comment: Yes. It was minimal example. I indeed need three columns in some cases. For one row, one column tabular is not required.

Comment: @user61681 anyway you will have made egreg very happy, he's always delighted when we both answer a question, and I get the green tick.

Comment: It is always helpful and pleasure to get responses from highly expertise people like you.

Answer (score 3):

I see no reason for a `tabular`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{breqn}

\begin{document}

You can see an important quantity in table~\ref{q-important}.

\begin{table}[htp]

\begin{dmath*}
  f (1.02) + f (1.06) + f (1.1)  + f (1.14) + f (1.18) + f (1.22) + 
  f (1.26) + f (1.3)  + f (1.34) + f (1.38) + f (1.42) + f (1)
\end{dmath*}

\caption{This is an important quantity\label{q-important}}

\end{table}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

*For referencing purpose. The output is put in a table which is referred*

You could remove the star and have a numbered equation to refer to. If you have a particular use case for captions, you may consider creating and formatting a custom float with a new label. It is also possible to format references.

Here is example code with an arbitrary new float `annotation`

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{breqn}
\usepackage{newfloat,caption,cleveref}

\DeclareFloatingEnvironment[
  fileext=note,
  listname={List of annotations},
  name=Annotation,
  placement=htp,
]{annotation}
\captionsetup[annotation]{position=bottom,skip=3pt}   % labelfont=bf
\crefformat{annotation}{Annotation~(#2#1#3)}

\usepackage{kantlipsum}   % for dummy texts


\begin{document}
% \listofannotations\vspace{\baselineskip}   % Creates a list of annotations

\kant[1][1]

\begin{annotation}
  \begin{dmath*}
    f (1.02) + f (1.06) + f (1.1)  + f (1.14) + f (1.18) + f (1.22) + 
    f (1.26) + f (1.3)  + f (1.34) + f (1.38) + f (1.42) + f (1)
  \end{dmath*}
  \caption{Sum of functions}\label{note:1}
\end{annotation}

\kant[1][2]

A regular reference: \eqref{note:1}, and reference with a label via \verb!cleveref!: \Cref{note:1}.
\end{document}
```

[image]